# How to prove geometrically that $\langle a-b,b-c\rangle=\frac{1}{2} (|a-c|^2-|a-b|^2-|c-b|^2)$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

It is straighforward to prove algebraically that if $a,b,c$ are points in the Euclidean plane, then $$\langle a-b,b-c\rangle=\frac{1}{2} (|a-c|^2-|a-b|^2-|c-b|^2).$$
However, actually this formula seems to have a very geometric flavour, i.e. a formula involving the area of the rectangle whose sides are $bc$ and the projection of the segment $ab$ onto $bc$ and the areas of the squares constructed on the sides $ab$, $bc$ and $ac$ respectively.

Does anyone see an elementary geometric proof of that formula?

Comment: Letting $u:=a-b$, $v:=b-c$, this becomes $\langle u,v\rangle = \frac12 (|u+v|^2-|u|^2-|v|^2)$. Rearranging, this is just $$|u+v|^2=|u|^2+|v|^2-2\langle u,v\rangle $$ which makes apparent the connection to the law of cosines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See picture, replacing $C$ by your $b$, $A$ by $a$ and $B$ by $c$.

This is the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

[image]

Another one:

[image]